# Response time difference with the usage of util.promisify

Tags: node.js, express, async-await, nodemailer

I was working on a project and I decided to convert everything to async/await. After learning how it works, I noticed that I could use the following without util.promisify().

```
await transporter.sendMail(message);
```

That happens because if we don't set the callback argument, the method returns a Promise. https://nodemailer.com/usage/

When I run it, it takes ~2000ms for the API to respond according to Postman but when I turn it into a Promise (with the help of util.promisify), it takes ~200ms to get a response, why is that?

```
await util.promisify(cb => transporter.sendMail(message, cb));
```

Am I doing something wrong or it's just promisify more optimized than the promise return?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because it's lying to you. You'll notice that your email isn't getting sent (so no waiting for emails which means less time).

`util.promisify()` does not return a Promise. It returns a **function that returns a Promise**:

```
const resultOfSendMail = transporter.sendMail(message); // notice, no await
console.log(resultOfSendMail instanceof Promise); // true

// however

const resultOfPromisify = util.promisify(cb => transporter.sendMail(message, cb));
                          // still no await
console.log(resultOfPromisify instanceof Promise); // false
console.log(resultOfPromisify instanceof Function); // true
```

The way you use Promisify is that you pass a function in, and you get a function out. Like so:

```
const sendMailAsync = util.promisify((msg, cb) => transporter.sendMail(msg, cb));
// sendMailAsync is a *function* that takes only message, and returns a Promise!
await sendMailAsync(message); // This returns a Promise! We can use await
```

You'll find that now, it takes approximately the same time to respond in both. And in both times, the email will actually be sent.

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining it, really helped a lot!

Comment: Now that I noticed, `const sendMailAsync = util.promisify((message, cb) => transporter.sendMail(message, cb));` does work but `const sendMailAsync = util.promisify(transporter.sendMail);` doesn't. Any clue why? It's not problematic since I think I grasped the concept of promisify but I'm curious about it.

Comment: @André I'm guessing that `sendMail` relies internally on `this` being the transporter. If that's the case, an arrow function will be properly bound, but a direct reference would not. If you still wish to use a direct reference, you would need to bind it, like so `util.promisify(transporter.sendMail.bind(transporter))`